# how to ignore SNAPSHOT dependency during Maven build?

Tags: maven, nexus, dependency-management

We try to build modules with release versions only.

We configured to use no SNAPSHOTS from remote repository at `settings.xml`:

```
<repositories>
    <repository>
      <id>public</id>
      <releases>
        <enabled>true</enabled>
      </releases>
      <snapshots>
        <enabled>false</enabled>
      </snapshots>
      <url>http://nexus...
```

But when running `mvn package` we get `Non-resolvable parent POM [...] Could not find artifact [...]:pom:0.1.2-SNAPSHOT`.

This error relates to the `maven-metadata-public.xml` at the local repository. Maven "knows" that there must be a `0.1.2-SNAPSHOT`:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<metadata>
  <groupId>***</groupId>
  <artifactId>***</artifactId>
  <versioning>
    <latest>0.1.2-SNAPSHOT</latest>
    <release>0.1.1</release>
    <versions>
      <version>0.1.1</version>
      <version>0.1.2-SNAPSHOT</version>
    </versions>
    <lastUpdated>20181212082933</lastUpdated>
  </versioning>
</metadata>
```

**How to force Maven to use version from `release` instead of `latest`?**

Already tried:
`versions:use-releases` `versions:use-latest-releases`

A possible work-around woud be to add a Nexus group repository containing releases only. - But we would like to solve this on the client side. - Also snapshots.enabled=false would be redundant.

Comment: You have to change the dependencies you are using and replace the versions with release versions which mean no `-SNAPSHOT`. Added a nexus group repository will not help here...

Comment: We have no explicit version, we are using a version range like `[0.1.1,0.1.99]`.

Comment: The following `pom:0.1.2-SNAPSHOT` says something different?

Answer (score 0):

While using version ranges is still possible, it is rather unusual nowadays.

You can try to call `versions:resolve-ranges` before the build, so that versions get resolved to concrete versions.